# Smaller quasi-cyclic LDPC code

Tags: error-correction

Recently, IBM proposed a new high-threshold and high-encoding-rate LDPC code family called [quasi-cyclic code](https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.07915). In the paper, they give the examples with the smallest [[72, 12, 6]] code.

My question is that whether there are [[$n$, $k$, $d$]] quasi-cyclic code with $n$ smaller than 72 as well as promising $k$, $d$ that can outperform surface code in the near-term hardware condition in which available number of physical qubits are around 100.

Comment: You should be able to design QCLDPC codes of smaller size either using the references in the paper or other methods. QCLDPC design is pretty mature for classical codes (WiFi, 5G, ... are all QCLDPC); some of this has been adapted to the quantum side (basically two such codes as a CSS pair). The main issue is performance; smaller codes are not as good. There's an additional parameter in the paper of circuit level noise so it won't be easy to compare codes without detailed simulations with the channel model.

Answer (score 3):

Many short codes are available in the online supplement to our [arXiv:2306.16400](https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.16400), located at [this github repository](https://github.com/QEC-pages/2BGA-codes). These include the usual generalized bicycle codes (cyclic groups $C_\ell$), two- and higher-dimensional index-two quasicyclic codes (for all abelian groups with two or more generators and group orders $\ell\le 50$ (code length $n=2\ell\le 100$), and similarly designed codes for all non-abelian groups of order $\ell$ of length $n=2\ell\le200$.

Comment: Nice paper...also nice to see the use of GAP in QECC

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the lifted product construction. How do you construct parity check matrices from a,b for the codes with 16 physical qubits from Table II for example?

Comment: You first need to construct the group. Then use Eq.(36) to construct the matrices A and B from the polynomials given.  Since the group is abelian with two generators of orders 4 and 2, respectively, the matrices have block structure, with two size-4 blocks. With the group presentation $\langle x,s|x^4=s^2=xsx^{-1}s^{-1}=1\rangle$ and polynomial a(x)=1+x, you get block-diagonal matrix with identical blocks $\displaystyle\left(\begin{array}[c]{cccc}1&0&0&1\\ 1&1&0&0\\ 0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&1\\\end{array}\right)$

Comment: Similarly, the polynomial $b(x)=1+x+x^2+s(1+x+x^3)$ has diagonal blocks
  $\displaystyle\left(\begin{array}[c]{cccc}1&0&1&1\\ 1&1&0&1\\
  1&1&1&0\\0&1&1&1\\\end{array}\right)$ generated by $1+x+x^2$
  and off-diagonal blocks
  $\displaystyle\left(\begin{array}[c]{cccc}1&1&0&1\\ 1&1&1&0\\
  0&1&1&1\\1&0&1&1\\\end{array}\right)$ generated by $1+x+x^3$.

Comment: Of course, this form is specific to the group elements ordered as $(1,x,x^2,x^3,s,sx,sx^2,sx^3)$.

Comment: Thank you! So $H_X$ is $\left(\begin{array}{llllllllllllllll}1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{array}\right)$?